# How to filter retweets and replies from Twitter User Stream using Twitter4j?

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using Twitter4j TwitterStream.user() to read the timeline for an authenticated user. I'm interested only in tweets from users that my user follows. 
About 99% of the statuses that I get from the stream are retweets and replies of users that my user doesn't follow. I'm filtering them out by maintaining a list of my user's following and checking each status against the list, and in addition I'm checking that status.getInReplyToStatusId is zero. It works but seems very inefficient since 99% of the data that I read is then filtered out.
Is there any way with twitter4j to instruct the user stream to send only original tweets without the retweets and replies?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can filter the replied tweets by a parameter, but I am not sure if it is implemented in twitter4j. But about retweets I think you have to filter out them manually.

From the user stream api:

> User streams messages
>
> Types of messages
>
> There are some streaming messages which are not returned by the REST
>   APIs. See streaming message types for information.
>
> Data from accounts the user follows
>
> The with parameter controls the types of messages received. The
>   default for User Streams is with=followings, which gives data about
>   the user and about the user’s followings (accounts which the
>   authenticated user follows). The setting with=user sends only events
>   about the user, and not events about their followings.
>
> Replies
>
> By default @replies are only sent from mutual followings. All @replies
>   by followings can be enabled with the replies=all parameter. For
>   example, if Alice follows Bob, but Alice doesn’t follow Carol, by
>   default if Bob @replies Carol, Alice does not see the tweet. The
>   default behavior mimics twitter.com and api.twitter.com behavior. If
>   an application wishes to display all @replies, or a filtered subset of
>   @replies, use replies=all.
>
> Direct messages
>
> Direct messages still require the proper permissions. See the
>   Application Permission Model.